# Multiple Java root causes to an exception

Tags: java, exception

I have an interesting scenario where I am setting an HttpServletResponse error in a catch clause. The "response.sendError(..)" also throws an exception. What is the best way to deal with exceptions during exception handling to preserve the original exception detail?

I have something like this:

```
try {
...
} catch(Exception e) {
  try {
      response.sendError(500);
    } catch(IOException e2) {
      //Can I do something like:
      //'throw new ServletException(e,e2)' here?
    }
}
```

In other words, what is the best way to bundle up the information from both exceptions into the next exception thrown? I don't want to lose the information from the first exception when handling the second.

In general, multiple try catch blocks seem horrible for readability. Would ideally like to avoid that mess. Could always bundle up the embedded try/catch in a method... still seems bad though and doesn't resolve keeping all the exception detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
...
} catch(Exception e) {
  try {
      response.sendError(500);
    } catch(IOException e2) {
      e2.initCause(e);
      throw e2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - did not realize that was possible... I guess you are out of luck if you are dealing with an exception that already has a root cause. Should be ok for this case though.

Comment: I think you can create more exceptions and chain them.

Comment: How do you handle if cause is already set on `e2`?  This is a bit tricky.  In your sample code, `e2.initCause(e);` will throw an exception if cause is already set on `e2`.

Answer (score 11):

Using `initCause()` will not aways work if the exception already has a cause.  Instead you can use `addSupressed()` to include the an exception in a different exceptions's stack trace.

```
try {
...
} catch(Exception e) {
  try {
      response.sendError(500);
    } catch(IOException e2) {
      e.addSuppressed(e2);
      throw e;
    }
}
```